# WCF \ SOA best practice for data consumption

Tags: wcf, soa

I'm trying my luck in WCF and I'm not sure how I should transfer data from the service to the client.

Lets say I have in my database a Worker entity and each worker has some tasks.
should the service transfer only the Worker entity, and than by additional request the tasks, or should the entity already include the tasks?

Comment: As always: *it depends* ! If you want to e.g. display a list of just workers - then transferring the whole tasks collection for each worker is useless and a waste of time. However, if you want to display a single worker, then transferring its tasks along with the Worker entity might make a lot of sense in order to avoid a second call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are correct. It would depend whether a worker could exist without tasks => is there a scenario where the clients will only fetch a worker? If yes, then you could have separate methods for fetching the worker and tasks. But if everytime clients send 2 requests because they always need the tasks associated to the worker then you are better off using an aggregate root. In terms of performance it's better to send one big request rather than multiple smaller requests.

Comment: Also known as "Chatty" vs "Chunky"

Comment: Together may seem to be a performance benefit, but in case the number of Tasks is large or it grows over time, this performance gain would be offset due to large payload. There is no correct answer, but only context driven solution.